# Azure Storage services logs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am a beginner in Azure and need some help. We are facing a bit of problem with Azure Storage services and are unable to proceed.

Ok now the issue is

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/05/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal.aspx

To summarize:
We have to inspect the log version of an/all of blobs,tables,queues in case any of them are using the one set for planned removal. I have enabled logging for the webapplication on the azure portal site. I am able to see the three services as under

https://.blob.core.windows.net

https://.table.core.windows.net

https://.queue.core.windows.net

Now in the articles as below I gather that we get the log format as this where they have a version included but have NOT  specfied from where to locate the logs and how to gather the logs. I have tried different things from  using https://.blob.core.windows.net/$logs but makes no difference.

The logs required should be  in this format(sample)

Here is a sample log entry, with the version used highlighted – in this case the request was an anonymous GetBlob request which implicitly used the 2009-09-19 version:

1.0;2011-08-09T18:52:40.9241789Z;GetBlob;AnonymousSuccess;200;18;10;anonymous;;myaccount;blob;"https:// myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/thumbnails/lake.jpg?timeout=30000";"/myaccount/thumbnails/lake.jpg";a84aa705-8a85-48c5-b064-b43bd22979c3;0;123.100.2.10;2009-09-19;252;0;265;100;0;;;"0x8CE1B6EA95033D5";Friday, 09-Aug-11 18:52:40 GMT;;;;"8/9/2011 6:52:40 PM ba98eb12-700b-4d53-9230-33a3330571fc"

Can you please show me a way to view these logs. Any tool to use ?

Comment: Are you "only" interested in finding out the storage service version your storage account is using? Or do you want to know how to view the storage logs?

Comment: I would like to know how to view the storage logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these logs are stored in a blob container called `$logs`, any storage explorer which supports viewing data from this blob container can be used to view the contents. To the best of my knowledge following tools support viewing data from this container: Azure Storage Explorer, Cerebrata Azure Management Studio, Cloud Portam (Disclosure: I am the developer working on this tool).

However before you could view the data you would need to enable logging on your storage account. Only when logging is enabled on the storage account you will see this container show up in your storage account. To enable logging, again you can use Azure Management Studio or Cloud Portam or you could use the code below (the code I mentioned below assumes you have the latest version of Storage Client Library):

```
    static void SetLoggingProperties()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(StorageAccount, StorageAccountKey), true);
        LoggingProperties properties = new LoggingProperties()
        {
            LoggingOperations = LoggingOperations.All,
            RetentionDays = 365,
            Version = "1.0",
        };
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties()
        {
            Cors = null,
            HourMetrics = null,
            MinuteMetrics = null,
            Logging = properties,
        };
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        blobClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        tableClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        var queueClient = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        queueClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
    }
```

Once logging properties are set, give it some time for logs to show up.

Comment: thanks gaurav. I am using Cerebrata tool. But may I know the steps to connect to the blobcontainer $logs. I tried to connect by using the subscription id but not giving any type of records. Also may I know in which type of logs will the entry for the storage version be ?

Comment: You can add a storage account by using account name/key. Once a storage account is added, you will see a node for `Storage Analytics`. Right click on it to configure analytics or double click on it to expand. Under `Raw Data` node, you will see `$logs`. Regarding you other question, if you look the data above in your question you will see `2009-09-19`. This is your storage service version. You can read more about the schema here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343259.aspx. HTH.

Comment: thanks again. But I am using the old version of Cerebrata version 2 named as Azure Diagnostics Manager. It seems that the option does not appear over there. Is there anything I am missing? The only options visible under when I expand the storage account node is Dashboard, event Logs,Trace logs,Infra Logs,Performance Counters, IIS logs,IIS failed request logs,Crash dumps

Comment: That product is retired. Check out this post from Cerebrata team on how you can get their Azure Management Studio product: http://blog.cerebrata.com/azure-management-studio-replaced-azure-diagnostics-manager-cloud-storage-studio/.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. That did the trick. Worked for me. But I can see several folders under "table" folder which are 2015--->01--->"19" and "20".under 19 I have number of folders starting from 0000 to 2300. Same for folders under "20" from 000 to 1300. What are these folders ? ?In which folder should I refer to have the correct log and correct version ?

Comment: Right. So basically the logs are prefixed by the date/time (in UTC with hour precision). You could possibly filter by prefix (e.g. `table/2014/12/01/0800`) and get to the logs directly. HTH.

Comment: ok..got it..so I have table/2015/01/20/files fromm0000.log to 0013.log. Which file to consider.

Comment: If you want to find out storage service version, pick any file as long as it has some data in it.

Comment: No I don't want to see the storage service version. I am concerned about this  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/05/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal.aspx. Actually I am confused. Do we have to check the GET BLOB request only.I am referring to "Check your application to find what versions it is using"

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. You need to check the storage service version which will tell you if you're using an older version of API or not. You can check any entry and that should do it. If you copy one of the log entries here, I can tell you which version is being used.

Comment: The log text is long. Not possible to paste the entries. It would give only truncated text. Actually I have a query between logs generared in two different folders. They both are showing different storage versions. I guess it depends on the type of request ?

Comment: Can you tell the request types and storage version shown?

Comment: There are actually numerous types of  request types. I need to sort out only get/put for which I stumbled on this now https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452235.aspx. Can you tell me how to test this Put/GET request  as   PUT https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties HTTP/1.1. By doing this I will be able to see the proper version.

Comment: IMHO, it's getting too much complicated now communicating via comments. Why don't you create a new question and provide all the details there.

Comment: Ok...sounds good. Will create a new question. Initially thought of sorting this out within one thread.

Comment: Created my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088345/seeking-version-of-blob-storage