# Seeking version of blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-blob-storage

Team,

I am a beginner in Azure and have some queries regarding the blob storage logs

I am referring to this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/05/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal.aspx

Now in my test environment I have enabled logging and I have got access to the log folders via Azure Management Studio.

When I look in the folders there are several mini folders I guess differentiated hr by hr. In that there are small txt files which get generated every 10 mins.

First question: How come the logs get generated even though there is no web activity ?

Second question : I have a problem with the storage version. The link given above talks about removing version before 2012. Does that mean I should only look at GetBlob/GetTable requests ?  The reason I am asking this is because along with the first Getblob request you have another request which is ListBlobs,Releaseblobs each with different version;

for eg

1.0;2015-01-22T09:25:05.1660119Z;**ReleaseBlobLease**;Success;200;8;8;authenticated.......;;; having version 2011-08-18

1.0;2015-01-22T09:26:51.2674946Z;**ListBlobs**;Success;200;4;4;authenticated;;autoenrolmenttest;blob......     having version 2012-02-12

1.0;2015-01-22T09:22:18.6111213Z;**PutBlob**;Success;201;13;12;authenticated;......... having version 2011-08-18

1.0;2015-01-22T09:25:06.0485334Z;**GetBlob**;Success;200;53;52;authenticated;....having version 2011-08-18

My predicament is which version I should consider from the above 4 ? Only getbllob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Logs containing requests certainly mean that there is an activity in your Azure Storage account. You can look at the client IP address to figure out where those requests are coming from.

2) Requests are independent and thus can be executed with different versions. All requests with an older version will not work after the version removal.

Comment: Thanks Serdar...that clears it. So I have to go for a storage version change finally.